# How to split a 3D matrix/volume into a fixed size sub-volumes and then re-merge in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, split

How can I split a 3D numpy array into fixed size 3D sub-arrays, do some manipulation on the sub-arrays, and finally put them back in the same order to create the original big 3D volume?

e.g. big volume is nxnxm

so, I would like to split it to sub-vlumes of k x k x k, and do some manipulation on each sub volume and put them together again to create nxnxm

Comment: This is much too vague. How do you want the pieces to be delivered? What do you want to do with them? What have you attempted? This is not a free coding service after all.

Comment: sorry I'm pretty new to python. I mean simple processing, e.g. applying a filter to each small volume then put them together. so, basically, it's splitting to smaller volumes and reverse the spliting to get the same original large vol

Comment: Show an example that is not optimized. It looks like you need a basic Python/numpy tutorial, not SO as the question stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to process your array with nested for-loops:

```
A = np.random.rand(5, 4)
print "A:", A

step = 2
newHeight = np.ceil(float(A.shape[0]) / step)
newWidth = np.ceil(float(A.shape[1]) / step)

B = np.zeros((newHeight, newWidth))
C = np.zeros(A.shape)
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        B[i, j] = np.mean(A[i*step:(i+1)*step, j*step:(j+1)*step])
        C[i*step:(i+1)*step, j*step:(j+1)*step] = B[i, j]
print "B:", B
print "C:", C
```

Output:

```
A: [[ 0.86754517  0.65107995  0.01074822  0.18394825]
 [ 0.03184878  0.07052286  0.44014168  0.84913463]
 [ 0.2982024   0.94988568  0.33208104  0.28697172]
 [ 0.36721371  0.9352932   0.22780242  0.13650031]
 [ 0.84073176  0.33792535  0.53240018  0.54008341]]
B: [[ 0.40524919  0.37099319]
 [ 0.63764875  0.24583887]
 [ 0.58932856  0.53624179]]
C: [[ 0.40524919  0.40524919  0.37099319  0.37099319]
 [ 0.40524919  0.40524919  0.37099319  0.37099319]
 [ 0.63764875  0.63764875  0.24583887  0.24583887]
 [ 0.63764875  0.63764875  0.24583887  0.24583887]
 [ 0.58932856  0.58932856  0.53624179  0.53624179]]
```

- `A` is the large input array
- `B` is the small output array
- `C` is the large output array
- `step` is the size of each block, 20 in your case
- `newHeight` and `newWidth` is the computed size of `B`: dividing the size of `A` by the window size `step` and rounding up
- `i*step:(i+1)*step` and `j*step:(j+1)*step` are the vertical and horizontal ranges for each block in `A` and `C`, respectively.

I'm using a small array of 5x4 as well as two dimensions only for simplicity and readability of the example results. It should be not to hard to extend this approach to three dimensions.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to split to smaller windows then put the smaller windows to go back to e.g. in your case to 5x4 again. For example, A is orginal 5x4, B is all the smaller non-overlaping 2x2 blocks, and C would be again 5x4. We are missing C here which is concatination of 2x2 blocks

Comment: @StackOverflower: Ok, I added an output array `C`.